# How to display error when there is nothing to fech from DB in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

below is a code to display table rows fetched from DB when the Sql Query returnes result.

```
<?php
if(isset(['submit']))
{
$key=$_POST['txt_srchKey'];
}



if($key!="")
{
$all_entries=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_book WHERE bookAuthor='$key'|| bookName='$key'||bookCode='$key' "); 
?>  
<table border=1 align="left">
<tr>
<td><b>Book Code</b></td><td><b>Book Name</b></td><td><b>Edition</b></td><td><b>Author</b></td>
</tr>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($all_entries))
{ ?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['bookCode'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['bookName'] ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row['bookEdition'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['bookAuthor'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}   
?>              
</table>
```

I am getting the result in the table when the condition (bookAuthor='$key'|| bookName='$key'||bookCode='$key')is true.but if there is no result it only showing the table headins eg:Book Code, Book Name etc. But instead of this I need to display 'No result found'.How can I do this by editing my code?

Comment: Firstly, this `if(isset(['submit']))` is invalid. It should read as `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without immediately getting into the problems with your code, you can use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

```
<?php
if(isset(['submit']))
{
    $key=$_POST['txt_srchKey'];
}
if($key!="")
{
    $all_entries=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_book WHERE bookAuthor='$key'|| bookName='$key'||bookCode='$key' "); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($all_entries) > 0)
    {
        ?>  
        <table border=1 align="left">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Book Code</b></td><td><b>Book Name</b></td><td><b>Edition</b></td><td><b>Author</b></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($all_entries))
        {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['bookCode'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['bookName'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['bookEdition'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['bookAuthor'] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }   
        ?>              
        </table>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?><p>No result found</p><?php
    }
}
```

There are a few things about this code that I should draw attention to:

---

**Issue 1**

This line is invalid:

```
if(isset(['submit']))
```

I think you mean to use:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

---

**Issue 2**

This SQL statement is wide-open to SQL injection:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_book WHERE bookAuthor='$key'|| bookName='$key'||bookCode='$key' ")
```

You could improve security on this by using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) when you set `$key` like this:

```
$key=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txt_srchKey']);
```

However, this is not a perfect solution in all cases, when brings me to my final point.

---

**Issue 3**

`mysql_query` and all the other `mysql_*` are deprecated in the latest versions of PHP. See the warning on the [`mysql_query` page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and the [**MySQL: choosing an API**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for more information. You may want to consider using MySQLi or PDO as making secure database queries is much easier in these extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :-

```
if(mysql_num_rows($all_entries) > 0){
<table border=1 align="left">
<tr>
<td><b>Book Code</b></td><td><b>Book Name</b></td><td><b>Edition</b></td><td><b>Author</b></td>
</tr>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($all_entries))
{ ?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['bookCode'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['bookName'] ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row['bookEdition'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['bookAuthor'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}   
?>              
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepend a condition before the `while` like this:

```
<?php 
    $number_of_results = mysql_num_rows($all_entries); 
    if ($number_of_results > 0) {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($all_entries)) { 
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['bookCode'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['bookName'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['bookEdition'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['bookAuthor'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php 
        } 
    } else {
?>   
<tr>
<td colspan="4">No results found</td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Please, be advised that the functions you're using right now are deprecated. They're also a common source for SQL injections and websites getting hacked. You could use something more adequate by using `PDO` or `MySQLi`.

Answer (score 0):

Before using `mysql_fetch_array` function always check records are coming from database or not

Using `mysql_num_rows` function

Example : `if(mysql_num_rows($all_countries) > 0)`

Add this code after your `</table>` tag

```
<?php   
      }   
       else  
       {         
          echo  "No Record Found";   
       }  
 ?>
```

if possible then use `!empty` instead of `isset` in your code